# In same page, how to get value from radio button and use it for the coming radio button

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

In same page, how to get value from radio button and use it for the coming radio button.

Example:

OCountry  OGender

If i selected Country, then the below radio button option will show:

OAmerica
OEngland
OAustralia
OMalaysia

But all of this is before submit button. Is all in one page.

So below is my code. Can anyone give me some advise?

1.Blade.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show1(){
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='none';
    }
    function show2(){
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
{!! Form::open(['action'=>'PostsController@store','method'=>'POST']) !!}
            <h2>Hi,{{Auth::user()->name}}</h2><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('roomkey','Key Number:')}}<br>
                    @foreach($rkeys as $rkey)
                    @if($rkey->status == "1")
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input onclick="show1()" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="roomkey" hidden selected><br>
                            <input 
                            onclick="show2()" 
                            class="form-check-input" 
                            type="radio" 
                            name="roomkey" 
                            value="{{$rkey->roomkey}}" 
                            disabled> 
                            {{$rkey->roomkey}}<br></div>
                    @else
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input onclick="show1()" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="roomkey" hidden selected><br>
                    <input onclick="show2()" class="form-check-input"  type="radio" name="roomkey" value="{{$rkey->roomkey}}" > {{$rkey->roomkey}}<br></div>
                    @endif
                    @endforeach
            </div>
//so this is the after the 1st part of radio button form.
                <div id="div1" class="hide">
                <hr><p>Room Number:</p>
                @foreach ($room as $room)
                @foreach($rkeys as $rkey)
                @if($rkey->roomkey == $room->roomkey)
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{$room->roomNum}}" name="roomNum">
                {{$room->roomNum}} &nbsp;
                @endif
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
                </div>
            <br>
            <input name="status" type="hidden" value="1">
            {{Form::submit('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value from radio button onclick and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515387/how-to-get-value-from-radio-button-onclick-and-use-it)

Comment: This seems like it is the exact same question even the code looks very similar

Comment: @Mike is the same actually, i forget to delete the old question, but is this sound more clear about my question?

Comment: jquery on change will do the trick, on change of OCountry = $('.countryListDiv').css('display','inline-block'); $('.genderDiv').css('display','none') and vice-versa. Make sure by default display none both div.